# BASH: Convert Unicode Hex to String

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, encode

I have this text file saved on my server, which contains Unicode letters in a hex decimal format, like `\u3010` etc. I want to convert them in order to make them human-readable without getting rid of the normal readable text like "Blessed Messiah and the Tower" etc.

```
\u3010Vocaloid 10\u3011Blessed Messiah and the Tower of AI\u3010Originl MV\u3011
\u3010Otomachi Una\u3011 Hate It! Hate It! Huge Ego!
\u3010Otomachi Una\u3011Melt \u3010Cover\u3011
\u3010GUMI\u3011 \u604b\u611b\u30c7\u30b3\u30ec\u30fc\u30c8 \u3010\u30aa\u30ea\u30b8\u30ca\u30ebMV\u3011
```

I already tried to run `cat FILE | hexdump -v` or `cat FILE | iconv -f utf16`, without any success. I even tried `cat FILE | ascii2uni -a U -q`, which was working, but there were a few graphical flaws, e.g.

```
【Otomachi Una】Melt over】
```

How can I encode these characters correctly? I would prefer commands that are built-in in most unix systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the same literals recognized by `echo -e` as representing Unicode characters.

```
$ echo -e "$(<FILE)"
【Vocaloid 10】Blessed Messiah and the Tower of AI【Originl MV】
【Otomachi Una】 Hate It! Hate It! Huge Ego!
【Otomachi Una】Melt 【Cover】
【GUMI】 恋愛デコレート 【オリジナルMV】
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to work, but for some reason, a few character sets do not get displayed correctly. I updated the question, where you can see that "【C" was not encoded correctly. I wonder why this is happening..

Comment: This is likely a problem with your terminal displaying the characters; if you pipe the output to a new file, then display *its* contents via `hexdump`, you should be able to see that all the characters are present.

Comment: My file is in UTF-8, it should be ASCII in order for this to work correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution :

```
printf '%s' "$(<file)"
```

[image]

where file is the name of the file containing your unicode text

Comment: `printf '%s' "$(<file)"` would be better, in case there are any percent signs in the input itself.